# easepick lockplugin filter on angular

Tags: angular

I'm testing [easepick hotel example](https://easepick.com/examples/hotel.html) *on Angular*.

I'm able to set minDate and maxDate but how can I filter custom dates?

[stackblitz to fork and play](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdv9a2-y4ngeq)

Thanks in advance for looking into this.

Comment: Please be specific about expected answer

Comment: Why did you voted down this? The title is talking about the filters, and I'm saying not sure how to filter.
I researched on easepick documentation (first link)
I've created a stackblitz example showing where I got stuck (commented code).
Have you at least seen the example and why it's not working?

Comment: I'm not the one who voted here. Let me check your example

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort this out: passing 'bookedDates' as another option to LockPlugin object.

That way the filter function can recognise this.bookedDates

You can see the working sample on [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdv9a2-3zccu8)

Hope this can help others struggling with similar issue.